# Deserialize byte[] from ASP Web Api IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I am trying work out the correct & best way to deserialize the response from a Asp.Net Web Api method that returns byte[].

The Web Api method looks like this

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    byte[] content = GetContent();
    return Ok(content);
}
```

I am calling the endpoint

```
string content;
using (var client =  new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/v1/thecorrectpath");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

When I read the response into `content` it is in the format below

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">SfSEjEyNzE9MNgMCD2a8i0xLjcNJeLjzC...R4Cg==</base64Binary>
```

What would be a best practice way to convert this response into a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for this.

Web API:

```
public string Get()
{
    byte[] content = GetContent();
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
    return data;
}
```

Client:

```
private static async Task GetData()
{
    string content;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:23306/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("home/get");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return binary data from a Web Api method. 
The ms object is a memory stream
You might want to set a more specific ContentType

On the server:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
return result;
```

Then on the client:

```
response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Nope, the content starts at `<base..` and not the nodes contents @Nathan Smith

Comment: Not sure why it's showing as xml but if you get the actualy base64 string out then you can use  Convert.FromBase64String which returns a byte[]

Answer (score 1):

First, install nuget package [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client) ;

Then use the generic extension method of http content:

`c#
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<byte[]>();`

It should works!